# ¿Como cambiar de color un link?

Tags: html, css

Buenas tardes,

Quiero cambiar el color de mi `<a href=""></a>` pero no logro hacerlo

Codigo CSS:

```
a:hover{

  color: #fff;
}
```

pero cambia el color al momento de pasar la flecha del raton sobre el link pero no logro hacer que cambie de color sin pasar el mouse

Comment: duplicado ??, que te hace pensar que es un duplicado?

Comment: Si te fijas, en la otra pregunta también quiere cambiar el color de un texto. No tiene porque ser duplicado al 100%, de hecho, en el otro ejemplo pregunta por cambiar el color del contenido de un `navbar`. Sin embargo, el resultado es el mismo sea un texto de un link o en un `navbar`.

Comment: de hecho no, @FranciscoRomero la pregunta que tu dices menciona "como cambiar el color de una letra" el mio dice "como cambiar el color de un link osea una etqueta "a" y en body no se puede hacer eso porque ya lo habia intentado

Comment: Pero lo que quiero decir es que entre cambiar el color de letra (texto) o cambiar el color de un link (texto) no hay diferencia. Se cambia con la propiedad `color` de CSS. Y también le puedes asignar un id al link para asignarle los estilos. No pretendo ofender, solo creo que son muy similares ambas preguntas y el medio para solventarlas es el mismo. De todas maneras, yo he abierto la posibilidad, la comunidad puede rechazar la propuesta si así lo cree conveniente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como esto:

```css
a{
  color: black;
}

a:hover{
  color: red;
}

a:active{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">Clic</a>
```

Usamos la sentencia:

```
a{
  color: black;
}
```

Para indicar el color ***Negro***, a los elemento de tipo `<a>`.

---

Usamos la sentencia:

```
a:hover{
  color: red;
}
```

Para indicar el color ***Rojo***, a los elemento de tipo `<a>`, cuando se pase el raton sobre ellos.

---

#### Actualizacion

Usamos la sentencia:

```
a:active{
  color: blue;
}
```

Para indicar el color ***Azul***, a los elemento de tipo `<a>`, cuando se presione con el raton sobre ellos. Es decir, cuando se haga clic.

---

#### Actualizacion 2

Si deseas hacer todo en una sola linea *(aunque no es muy recomendable porque no se podria centralizar el diseño en otro archivo)*.

Podrias hacer algo asi:

```html
<a href='index.html' style='color: black'>Clic</a>
```

Aunque este solo funcionaria para el color **en general**, mas no para los eventos `hover` o `active`.

Comment: Gracias :3 funciono

Comment: Que bien que te haya funcionado

Comment: es lo mas sensillo del mundo pero yo no lo recordaba  XD

Comment: en 10 minutos acepto tu respuesta ya que no me deja hacerlo ahora

Comment: Genial, lo importante es que te haya funcionado, he agregado un par de actualizaciones, como cultura general para futuros usuarios :)

Comment: si es una muy buena ayuda :3

Answer (score 1):

No tienes más que quitar el `:hover` que es el que indica que es un estilo que debe aplicarse al pasar por encima el ratón

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;
}

a{
   color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Link color</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar el color sin mause hover:

```css
a {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p><b><a href="enlace.jsp" target="_blank">texto en linkk</a></b></p>
```

Mayor referencia sobre CSS Link: 
[CSS Styling](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_link)